# WaitGif Form - Coordinated cancellation of thread (via token) with Cancel Button in Spawned Form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task, token, animated-gif

I am using a class to load a waitgif form (via threading), attributed to @nobugz [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58cd891d-e7b8-45e2-9401-2b2f03c8bd97/quotloadingquot-animated-gif-display-on-different-thread-while-loading-a-form?forum=winforms).  The spawned waitgif form has a cancel button.  The problem is that I need the class that spawned the thread (waitgif form) to listen for a cancelled token from the spawned form.  So can I feed the token to the threaded waitgif form via a property, so that upon cancellation the parent thread will terminate?

Also, as a general question, whenever `t.Source.Cancel` is used in a method of an instantiated class, can it be followed by `Me.Dispose` based on the declaration `Implements IDisposable` to speed up memory availability without forcing garbage collection?

```
Public Class PleaseWait
    Implements IDisposable
    Private mSplash As New Form
    Private mLocation As Point
    Shared t As New TokenPOC()

    Sub New(ByVal location As Point)
        mLocation = location
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state) workerThread(), t.Token)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Dispose()
        If mSplash.IsHandleCreated Then
            mSplash.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf stopThread))
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub stopThread()
        mSplash.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub workerThread()
        mSplash = Form_WaitGif
        mSplash.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        mSplash.Location = mLocation
        mSplash.TopMost = True
        Application.Run(mSplash)
    End Sub
End Class 

Public Class Form_WaitGif
    Private Sub Form_WaitGif_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToScreen()
        LoadDataFormAbort = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        t.Source.Cancel()  'Not recognized
        Me.Dispose()  'Is this needed when killing large classes to free up memory without forced GC?
        Label1.Left = 100
        Label1.Text = "Please wait - Terminating data loading (may take a while for large files...)"
    End Sub
    Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
      'Dispose(True)
       GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Looks familiar, copied without attribution [from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58cd891d-e7b8-45e2-9401-2b2f03c8bd97/quotloadingquot-animated-gif-display-on-different-thread-while-loading-a-form?forum=winforms)

Comment: Attribution fixed.   The problem is getting the class which spawns the thread to listen for cancellation of its token within the threaded form.